# How to edit a lacklustre answer so it passes peer review?

Tags: discussion, edits

Several times in my life of using SO as a resource to get my problem solved I come across what I consider a half-effort in an answer. It leads me to the right result in the end, but there were a good stack of additional problems to overcome with it, that really should have been part of the original solution

One example was in the following form:

> Q: How can I load a file in (a particular context) if I'm using cache system Y
>
> A (from someone else): Do this: `y.load(file)`

That's fine if you only do it once per file, but say there's a high chance that the same file will attempt to be loaded twice and cache Y throws a particularly nasty error if you load twice. I thus regarded the answer as a half-hearted effort and I added some detail:

> A: Do this: `y.load(file)` Note: you can only load a file once so if you envisage a situation where the same file may be scheduled for load multiple times, a code pattern like this would be more appropriate: `if(not y.contains(file)) y.load(file)`

I want to make it clear that in the original story that gave rise to this question my edit wasn't just a 1 liner tidbit of advice that would fit in a comment - the above contrived scenario I describe is a short short version of an edit i suggested that ran to tens of lines of explanation, code samples, example data etc

The edit was rejected by peer review and my edits generally attract rejection reasons of *"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."*

My perspective is that ALL my edits are with the intention of adopting the tone of the answering person, and writing TO the original questioner and they're done as edits because there's no way they would fit meaningfully in a comment because of formatting/length/volume of info but they can't stand on their own as an answer without plagiarising the other poster because they are (IMHO valid) improvements to the solution the other person proposed rather than being a nbetter answer in their own right. I simultaneously don't want to take away from their original inspiration in answering the question nor pollute the site with duplicate info from their post

So what do you do when you want to flesh out a half-hearted answer? Or improve an answer that outlines e.g. 6 steps but you know that 3 of them are erroneous/a bad way to do things?

Comment: If you feel the answer is incomplete and lacks important information then I suggest you write your own answer.  You don't want to put words and code in someone else's mouth because if it is wrong (not saying it is) then they are on the hook, not you.

Comment: If their inspiration is reasonable but their implementation flawed, do I credit them if I'm taking their stuff and improving it?

Comment: Sure, you can always say your answer is inspired/carries on from the other users answer.

Comment: Here is an example of one I wrote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32888252/4342498

Comment: @NathanOliver Not just *can*, but *must*.  If you're using another person's original works in your code you *need* to cite them.  It's not optional.

Answer (score 25):

How do you get your edits approved?  You don't. The edits are being correctly rejected.

It's not plagiarism for you to post your own answer, so long as you appropriate cite the portions of your answer that aren't yours.  (Obviously if you fail to cite the works that aren't yours, *then* it would be plagiarism.)  If you have additional information, such as the example that you've given, that you want to add, and you feel that it's too much information to go over in comments, then you should be posting a new answer.

Answer (score 9):

Since you needed to ask a question I would assume that you are not an expert in that particular field.  As such you might not know the implications of your "improvements" and/or better ways to reach the same result.

You may also consider the possibility that you are not the ultimate authority on what the proper answer should look like.

With this in mind it becomes reasonable to add your own answer (as a peer to other answers) with all applicable attributions and not to try to create a perfect answer by changing somebody's work way beyond the intention of its author.

Answer (score 2):

> So what do you do when you want to flesh out a half-hearted answer?

Simple. Obvious and minor mistakes I correct on the fly. In all other cases (such as the one you mentioned), I notify the answerer of the shortcomings of this answer with a comment first. If then he doesn't react and improve the answer, I may post my own (hopefully) superior answer. I give credit where credit is due. I may also downvote bad answers at any time.